# why only the first span is visible and others are hidden

Tags: css

I am new to CSS so please excuse if this s basic question ,

I am trying to develop a similar User Interface as show in this picture below

[image]

This is my code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="marquee-sibling">Indices </div>
  <div class="marquee">
    <ul class="marquee-content-items">

      <li><span>NASDAQ</span><br>
      <span>4655.92</span>
      <span>17.93</span>
      <span>0.39%</span>
      </li>

      <li><span>DJIA</span><br>
      <span>16414.39</span>
      <span>15.82</span>
      <span>0.1%</span>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

But could you please tell me why only the first span is visible and others are hidden ??

http://jsfiddle.net/Wf43X/319/

Comment: You must post your CSS, otherwise, we'd never know why

Comment: No. But you need to read [ask].

Comment: sorry forgot to put my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wf43X/319/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with **Flexbox**

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  paddgin: 10px;
}

li span {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li > span:nth-child(4n+2),
li > span:nth-child(4n+4) {
  text-align: right;
} 

li > span:nth-child(4n+1),
li > span:nth-child(4n+2) {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
} 

li > span:nth-child(4n+3),
li > span:nth-child(4n+4) {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="marquee-sibling">Indices </div>
  <div class="marquee">
    <ul class="marquee-content-items">

      <li>
        <span>NASDAQ</span>
        <span>4655.92</span>
        <span>17.93</span>
        <span>0.39%</span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <span>DJIA</span>
        <span>16414.39</span>
        <span>15.82</span>
        <span>0.1%</span>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your beautiful work , working like charm .

Answer (score 2):

I have tried something like this..

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.marquee {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.container{  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
 }
.ind-cont {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.txtcolor {
  color: #fff;
}

.txtcolorb {
  color: #aaa;
}

.ind-name {
  margin: 20px;
}

.capital {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.one-share {
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="marquee-sibling"> </div>
  <div class="marquee">
    <span class="ind-cont">
        <span class="ind-name txtcolor ">NASDAQ</span>
    <span Class="capital txtcolor">4655.92</span>
    <span class="one-share txtcolorb">17.93</span>
    <span class="per txtcolorb floatright">0.39%</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ind-cont">
        <span class="ind-name txtcolor ">DJIA</span>
    <span Class="capital txtcolor">16414.39</span>
    <span class="one-share txtcolorb">15.82</span>
    <span class="per txtcolorb floatright">0.1%</span>
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking a line after the first span, and this code is hiding whatever is after the first line:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 45px;
}
```

Comment: you mean that i should put this code in my css to make it work ?

Comment: Could you please let me know how to fix it ??

Comment: I fixed a few things around, not to make the whole thing look like that picture, but to make the spans show: http://jsfiddle.net/Wf43X/325/

Answer (score -1):

I also think that the flexbox ideas is the best but if you still want to stay with your code, I think you should try changing the size height of your .container in your css. you will be able to see the rest of your 'li' element. The text is in white color and you can't really see it when you run your code cause the background is white.